# Google Apps Script: Move data between spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to move data between two Google spreadsheets.

The spreadsheet named Ex_ID has one sheet and one row for each employee, each row has six important values including an id number and five data values.

The spreadsheet named CR_ID has a different sheet for each employee and each sheet has an id number and five cells where I need to enter the data.

I'm trying to write a script that moves data values from Ex_ID to CR_ID where the id values match.  (Note: Since I'm still trying to see how the code can work, I limited the example to one of the five data values and I'm only testing it on three employees.)

```
function myFunction() {
  var CR_ID = "1BbAmoSsS_2-nvOxv_l5gZ8ftXclD5muWs0ZAmkDUR-Y";
  var ssCR = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CR_ID);
  var sCR = ssCR.getSheets();
  var Ex_ID = "1lkpXdWdbfe8Wkj1RGQOb-pWjEQe41hstKj2i4TxMQd8";
  var ssEx = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Ex_ID);
  var sEx = ssEx.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for (var i = 2; i = 4; i++) {
    //Get id value from Ex_ID 
    var ExCell = sEx.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    for (var j = 0; j = 2; j++) {
      var sheet = sCR[j];
      //Get id value from CR_ID
      var val = sheet.getRange(1, 7).getValue();
      if (ExCell[i] == val[j]) {
        var ExWrite = sEx.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
        sheet.getRange(3, 20).setValue(ExWrite);
      }    
    }  
  }
}
```

Best,

Mayne Dela

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your data is organized and where you want to put them on the sheets but I would try something like this:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var ess = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BbAmoSsS_2-nvOxv_l5gZ8ftXclD5muWs0ZAmkDUR-Y");
  var es = ess.getSheets();

  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lkpXdWdbfe8Wkj1RGQOb-pWjEQe41hstKj2i4TxMQd8");
  var ds = dss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dr = ds.getDataRange();
  var dA = dr.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<dA.length;i++)//started with 1 assuming that you have a header.  
  {
      var row=dA[i];//loop through rows of employee data I will assume data to be in this  ID,DataValue1,DataValue2,DataValue3,DataValue4,DataValue5
      for(var j=0;j<es.length;j++)
      {
        if(row[0]==es[j].getSheetName())//checking the ID value assuming it is row[0];
        {
          var sht=es[j];
          sht.getRange('D1').setValue(row[1]);//DataValue1
          sht.getRange('D2').setValue(row[2]);//DataValue2
          etc...
        }

      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! To make it work I had to modify my data a little bit.  Originally I used the employee names for sheet names in ess and then I stored the id inside of the sheets (in cell G1).  I modified the data so that dss has employee names where I used to store the id.  Since sheets can't have the same name, I should be fine with this.  Thanks!